# regular expression of a binary string of odd length and 0 as the middle symbol

Tags: regex

regular expression of a binary string of odd length and `0` as the middle symbol. having trouble in figuring out how to maintain having a 0 in the middle. (left part made up of binary numbers + `0` + same as the left part). so far i made it till `((01)(0+1)*0)U((01)(0+1)*)`, but still wrong. only able to use `+`, `*` and `U`

Comment: If the string is of arbitrary length, it cannot be done with regular expressions.

Comment: I take it this is some kind of assignment? What's that `U` doing there?

Comment: does it have to be unambiguous?

Comment: I think this is about [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and not regex per se.

Answer (score 2):

> regular expression of a binary string of odd length and 0 as the middle symbol.

That's not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), but a [context-free one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language). It might be produced by the grammar

```
S → LSL | 0
L → 0 | 1
```